# create new IITM Synopsis template. Colour right side of page

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage

[image]

I tried to do it using a minipage, but the overall margin setting does not allow me to do so.
is there any way to change margin setting for just one page and create this title page ?

Answer (score 1):

`eso-pic` package can help you to add the blue line on background.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{This is the title}
\author{me}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \color{cyan}%
    \rule{2cm}{\paperheight}%
  }
}

\maketitle

\chapter{1}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]